# Это устройство было остановлено, поскольку оно сообщило о возникновении неполадок. (Код 43)

Tags: железо, драйвер, видеокарта

Установил драйвера на видеокарту,появилась данная ошибка,а при входе или при загрузке AMD Catalys выдает ошибку,что драйвер функционирует не правильно[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
ПОМОГИТЕ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Удалить компонент вместе с драйвером, попробовать полностью обновить винду, попробовать найти на оф сайте дрова конкретно под этот чип и поставить их.

Comment: на amd hd 7600m есть на офф сайте,а на hd 7640g нет,что посоветуете?

Comment: А процессор у вас не AMD A8-4500M? Я думаю вам должен подойти [этот драйвер](https://www.amd.com/ru/support/apu/amd-series-processors/amd-a8-series-apu-for-laptops/a8-4500m-radeon-hd-7640g).

Comment: Да,верно,мне удалить все драйвера ?и установить этот?

Comment: Удалите компонент amd catalyst сначала, через удаление и установку, там может быть галочка что то типа "удалить также драйвер", если нет, то драйвер отдельно, скачайте и поставьте тот что я скинул и обязательно обновите windows

Comment: не получается ничего,я уже не знаю что делать

Comment: у Вас больше нет идей?

Comment: Качать дрова с сайта производителя ноута пробовал?

Comment: Да,пробовал.....